# Brightness adjustment broken - Lenovo Yoga 6 13ARE05

Tags: release-hera, keyboard, power, lenovo, brightness

Installed 5.1.7 Hera on my laptop (Lenovo Yoga 6 13ARE05); everything *except* brightness control seems to be working great. Brightness keyboard controls and System Settings -> Power -> Display Brightness slider are syncing/working, but do not affect the screen brightness. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend experimenting with some of the kernel command-line options mentioned in [Ubuntu's Backlight Debugging Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Debugging/Backlight) and the ones listed in the Arch Linux Wiki's [Backlight page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Backlight#Kernel_command-line_options).

If you still can't get the backlight to work, I recommend sending a bug report to Ubuntu's kernel team as outlined in [Ubuntu's Backlight Debugging Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Debugging/Backlight).

You can also try [color correction with xrandr](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Backlight#Xorg:_adjust_perceived_brightness_with_xrandr), but this is more of a hack that simulates brightness adjustment without actually controlling the backlight.
This won't save power or accurately preserve colors.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did try the suggested kernel command line options with no success. Will send a bug report to Ubuntu. EJ

Comment: You're welcome! I just submitted a bug report yesterday for my machine's backlight having similar problems. In elementary OS 5.1  the linux-bug program won't work, fyi. I submitted my bug report [directly on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+filebug).